# How do I share my variables and my function output in parallel computing?

Tags: parallelization

Here as a simple example

[image]

```
nnn = 81; 
x = Subscript[A, i]; y = Subscript[B, i];
Do[Subscript[A, i] = 5 i + 2, {i, 1, nnn}]; 
Do[Subscript[B, i] = 3 i , {i, 1, nnn}];

function = y - x + Sqrt[(2 y - x)^2]
ParallelDo[Subscript[F, i, j] = function, {i, 1, nnn, 1}, {j, 1, nnn, 1}]
```

I just want the share my input variable and my output in all my CPU processors
I already use `DistributeDefinitions` and `SetSharedVariable`, `SetSharedFunction`.  It works with `ParallelTable`, but with `ParallelDo` it's not working, especially when I use symbols with index `fi` as shared variable input or a shared functions output.  I have no problem with the variable without indices. The problem occurs when I use symbols `fi`  with an index. When I use `[F, i, j]` in anther computation, it does not work.

Comment: Look up the help file on `DistributeDefinitions`.

Comment: First, thank you all for your interesting
So what’s my problem exactly?
I just want the share my input variable and my output in all my CPU processors
I already use DistributeDefinitions and SetSharedVariable SetSharedFunction  its work with ParallelTable  But with ParallelDo she’s not working especially when I use  symbols with index  fi as shared variable input  or a shared functions output  I have no problem with the variable without index the problem begin when I use symbols fi  with index

Comment: For example
nnn = 80;
Do[Subscript[A, i] = 5 i + 2, {i, 1, nnn, 1}]
Do[Subscript[B, i] = 5 i, {i, 1, nnn, 1}]
x = Subscript[A, i];
y = Subscript[B, i];
fuction = y - x + Sqrt[(2 y - x)^2];
ParallelDo[
 Subscript[F, i, j] = fuction, {i, 1, nnn, 1}, {j, 1, nnn, 1}]  when i want [F, i, j] in anther camputing its not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, drop the `Subscript` notation -- it is only asking for trouble. Parallelization tasks are finicky enough without trying to confuse the kernel with layers of nested variables. So let us instead define all quantities like `Subscript[A,x,y]` as `A[x,y]` etc.

```
nnn = 81;
x[i_] = A[i]; y[i_] = B[i];
Do[A[i] = 5 i + 2, {i, 1, nnn}];
Do[B[i] = 3 i, {i, 1, nnn}];
function1[i_] = y[i] - x[i] + Sqrt[(2 y[i] - x[i])^2];
function2[i_, j_] = y[j] - x[i] + Sqrt[(2 y[j] - x[i])^2];
```

Notice that I added an argument to `x` and `y`, since it actually makes a difference when you define your `function` variable. I also defined `function1` and `function2` to demonstrate how having different `i,j` labels affects your definitions. In one case it is independent of `j`, in the other both `i` and `j` show up.

Next, since you want to use this in parallel computing, let us evaluate these lines on each parallel kernel as well, to make these definitions available locally on each kernel (this makes parallel calculations much faster than trying to share them from the global context):

```
ParallelEvaluate[
  nnn = 81;
  x[i_] = A[i]; y[i_] = B[i];
  Do[A[i] = 5 i + 2, {i, 1, nnn}];
  Do[B[i] = 3 i, {i, 1, nnn}];
  function1[i_] = y[i] - x[i] + Sqrt[(2 y[i] - x[i])^2];
  function2[i_, j_] = y[j] - x[i] + Sqrt[(2 y[j] - x[i])^2];
  ];
```

To illustrate how to use the `ParallelDo` to write to a shared variable, let us share the function name `F` with all kernels

```
SetSharedFunction[F]
```

it has to be `SetSharedFunction` instead of `SetSharedVariable` because we intend to write and save values such as `F[1,2]` etc. which take function arguments. Finally, your parallel do command can be either one of:

```
ParallelDo[F[i, j] = function1[i], {i, 1, nnn, 1}, {j, 1, nnn, 1}]
```

or

```
ParallelDo[F[i, j] = function2[i,j], {i, 1, nnn, 1}, {j, 1, nnn, 1}]
```

depending on your actual intended definition of `function`. In the above, `F[i,j]` values will be calculated in parallel on the sub-kernels and communicated back to the main kernel since `F` is a shared function. However, you will notice that this simple example actually takes more time to calculate in parallel than without parallelization. The reason is that each `F[i,j]` has to first be distributed in chunks to the parallel kernels, then collected and stored back into the global context on individual basis. Having a bigger calculation might increase this trouble.

Perhaps it might be more efficient to store the data in global context by avoiding the use of any shared variables and requesting the output to be delivered back to main kernel in the form of a list, e.g.

```
FF = ParallelTable[ function1[i], {i, 1, nnn, 1}, {j, 1, nnn, 1}];
```

or

```
FF = ParallelTable[ function2[i,j], {i, 1, nnn, 1}, {j, 1, nnn, 1}];
```

then you can access the desired `F[i,j]` elements as `FF[[i,j]]` instead, and the calculation returns much faster.

Comment: Thank you very much sir it works well